# CentOS 7 installation: partition problems and corrupted UI

Tags: centos, system-installation

I'm trying to install CentOS 7 to HP Z440 workstation having (some kind of) RAID setup. The default installation fails with screen full of garbled text apparently with some kind of serious system error (no mouse clicks work), and text-based installation (using `linux text`) fails with Anaconda stacktrace from blivet.errors.DeviceTreeError. If I press "Debug", I get to see the error being thrown from addUdevPartitionDevice, and on continuing there the error seems to be "DeviceTreeError: failed to scan disk RAID1Volume_0".

Based on these [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1164568) [reports](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1157657) and especially [this comment](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1164568#c18) it seems to be a known issue when partition data has issues.

The question is, how to go forward from here? I guess I need to repartition the disks, but does CentOS boot disk offer something to do it, and if so, what? What am I exactly meant to do, delete the partitions and recreate them, or something else? I don't need to store any data from this computer, everything is ok to wipe away.

---

Edit: I managed to get into Anaconda Shell in text-based install using alt+f2, and `fdisk -l` tells me that "Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary", which is probably my issue.

Edit2: I also see "Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes" in there, making the question probably related to [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156994/partition-does-not-start-on-physical-sector-boundary). I could just recreate the partition, but what about the raid setup? Currently fdisk and p says:

```
device boot      start         end        blocks   id System
/dev/md126p1      2048      499711        248832   83 Linux
/dev/md126p2    501658  3907016703    1953257473    5 Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/md126p3    501760  3907016703    1953257472   83 Linux
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did two things to get this going:

1) on the partitioning problem leading to anaconda stack trace: select anaconda console and start up fdisk on /dev/yourdrive. Check your partitions by pressing 'p'. Then delete ('d') the partition 2 (the raid copy will be gone as well). Write your changes ('w') and exit fdisk. Reboot. Then proceed to install.

2) on the malformed UI: just using text-mode install seems to work around it. To do that, just press ESC on the first installation/troubleshooting selection screen and write `linux text`.

Of course, when actually starting up all the text and icons were again malformed. I got that fixed by

1. Finding out which video card I had using lspci -v | less
2. Downloading appropriate NVIDIA drivers on another computer with graphic interface
3. setting up ssh on the target machine, `yum -y install openssh-server openssh-clients`
4. sending files there
5. login to target machine as root
6. `init 3`
7. `yum -y update`
8. `yum -y install kernel-devel kernel-headers gcc make`
9. ./NVIDIA*.run
10. `init 5`